# jquery issue checkbox that hides the input next to it

Tags: jquery

i have a lot of checkboxes and for each one i have an input field next to it
i want when i click on each checkbox .. the input next disapear ! so i did this .. and it looks logical to me but it's a mess

```
$(":checkbox").click(function() {
    $(":checkbox").next().hide();
});
```

but it hides all the inputs of the documents
so i tryed this

```
this.next().hide();
```

but it's not working !
i tried this in staid !

```
for(i=0;i<$(":checkbox").length;i++){
  $(":checkbox").eq(i).click(function() {
      $(":checkbox").eq(i).next().hide();
   });
}
```

and still not working ! what's wrong with my logic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to use as a selector for your checkboxes is this -

```
$('input:checkbox');
```

Secondly, within the callback of the click handler, you can use the `$(this)` keyword to access the specific element that created the event.

```
$("input:checkbox").on('click',function() {
  $(this).next().hide();
});
```

I like to be very verbose with my selectors to improve readability, so as a final suggestion, why not give a selector to the `next()` function and specify that you want to look for the next `input` element?

```
  $(this).next('input').hide();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
  $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
$(":checkbox").click(function() {
    $(this).next().hide();
});
```

`this` and `$(this)` are quite different, I'd recommend reading through the jQuery documentation for more information as it is pretty fundemental...